# Analytics for Apache Hadoop - what files are uploaded for Analyzing data with Oozie?

Tags: ibm-cloud, analytics-for-hadoop, analytics-for-apache-hdp

The Analytics for Apache Hadoop documentation lists the following steps for analysing data with Oozie:

> #### Analyzing data with Oozie
>
> 1. Install required drivers.
> 2. Use webHDFS to [upload the workflow related files to HDFS](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/AnalyticsforHadoop/index.html#analyticsforhadoop_data).
>
>    For example, upload the files to `/user/biblumix/apps/oozie`
> 3. ...
>
> Source: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/AnalyticsforHadoop/index.html

**Question**: What files are typically uploaded in step 2?  The wording suggests that the files are oozie files (e.g. xml files).  However, the link takes you to the section [Upload your data](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/AnalyticsforHadoop/index.html#analyticsforhadoop_data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I performed some testing, and I had to upload a workflow.xml in addition to the data files that my oozie job processes.